# Links from Lexicon to text (glossary)

Tags: hyperref, links, glossary

I'm writing a report. At the end of this report, I make a lexicon with the list of every complex word I used. Each time one of these word appears in the text, I create a `\hyperlink` to link the word to a section* with some explanations in the lexicon.

Those words can appear several times in the text, so I'd like to have something that allows you to go back where you were reading (either an arrow to go back to where you came from, or display page numbers like backref does in bibliographies).

Here is an example of what I want.

```
\documentclass[12pt,UKenglish]{article}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}


\section{Intro}
\blindtext
\hyperlink{sec:FirstComplexWord}{first complex word}


\blindtext
\hyperlink{sec:SecondComplexWord}{second complex word}

\newpage

\blindtext
\hyperlink{sec:SecondComplexWord}{second complex word}


\blindtext
\hyperlink{sec:FirstComplexWord}{first complex word}


\newpage
%every section, subsection, ... doesn't have numbers
\section*{Lexicon}
\phantomsection
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Lexicon}


\subsection*{First complex word}\hypertarget{sec:FirstComplexWord}{}
\phantomsection
\addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{First complex word}

Blabla bla

Something here to go back 

\subsection*{Second complex word}\hypertarget{sec:SecondComplexWord}{}
\phantomsection
\addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{Second complex word}

Blabla bla

Something here to go back 

\end{document}
```

Comment: Isn't go back a feature of almost all PDF viewers? For example in okular it is Alt + Shift + Arrow Left.

Comment: you could look at glossaries package as an alternative to making all the links by hand